# Two-Way Binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, binding

In my *Silverlight* project I am creating textboxes which are *two-way databound* to some Context during runtime. The binding in one direction (*from the source to the target*) seems to work fine, but the other direction (*from the target back to the source*) is not showing any effect.

**This is the data-context:**

```
public class Leg : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string passengers;

    public string Passengers {
        get { return passengers; }
        set {
            // here I have a breakpoint.
            passengers = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Passengers"); 
         }
    }

    private void FirePropertyChanged (string property) {

        if (PropertyChanged != null) {

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Then on another place I am creating a new TextBox control together with a binding for it:**

```
Binding passengersBinding = new Binding();

// viewModelLeg is an instance of the class Leg from above    
passengersBinding.Source = viewModelLeg;

passengersBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Passengers");
passengersBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

legItem.paxTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, passengersBinding);
```

Now when I am altering the value of the Passengers string the corresponding textbox that is bound to it is updating its text correctly. **So here's everthing fine.**

But when i change the text of a textbox manually and then make the textbox lose its focus, nothing happens - i.e. there is no two-way binding taking place - no down propagation of the new text-value of the textbox to the source !

I have a breakpoint at the setter of the passengers-attribute (marked with the breakpoint-comment above). *When I am getting all this right the binding engine also uses this public setter when the target-value of a binding has changed to update the source - so when this happens the breakpoint must be hit.* **But he doesn't !** So it seems that i can do what I want with my textbox (play with the focus or press enter) it is never updating its source.

Am I overseeing something ? There must be a capital error either in my code or in my thinking.. i would be really thankful for any ideas ...

**EDIT:**

In the following I try to demonstrate how i create my XAML objects and my DataContext objects. Because I am creating XAML controls and their bindings at runtime I haven't found a good solution to implement the MVVM approach very well. So I am doing the following (which is maybe not the best way to do it):

The situation I am modelling is that I have a UserControl (called LegItem) which is comprised (primarely) of textboxes. At runtime the user can create as much of these userControls as hew wishes to (one after the other).

On my ViewModel side I have a class (called Leg) that serves as a ViewModel for exactly one LegItem. So when I have say n (XAML-) LegItems then I also have n Leg instances. I store these Leg objects in a List.

So I am doing the following everytime the user clicks the 'add a new leg' button:

```
// here we are inside the applications view in an .xaml.cs file

public void AddLeg () {

    // this is going to serve as the ViewModel for the new LegItem
    // I am about to create.
    Leg leg = viewModel.insertLeg();

    // here I am starting to create the visual LegItem. The ViewModel object
    // I have created in the previous step is getting along with.
    createLegItem(leg);
}

// the primary job here is to bind each contained textbox to its DataContext.
private LegItem createLeg (Leg viewModelLeg) {

    // create the visual leg item control element
    // which is defined as a XAML UserControl.
    LegItem legItem = new LegItem();

    Binding passengersBinding = new Binding();

    // viewModelLeg is an instance of the class Leg from above    
    passengersBinding.Source = viewModelLeg;

    passengersBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Passengers");
    passengersBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

    legItem.paxTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, passengersBinding);

}


// on the viewModel side there is this simple method that creates one Leg object
// for each LegItem the View is creating and stores inside a simple list.

public Leg InsertLeg () {

    Leg leg = new Leg();
    legList.add(leg)

    return leg;
}
```

Comment: When you say you "change the text of a textbox manually", do you mean typing something in the TextBox or setting `SomeTextBox.Text = "SomeValue"`? Because the 2nd way is overwriting the binding, so the `TextBox.Text` property is no longer bound.

Comment: Are you also setting a binding in xaml?  If so, it's possible that your xaml binding is overriding your custom binding. (depending on where the code above sits)

Comment: @Rachel: No, I am taking the first approach. Selecting the textbox with my cursor, writing some text inside it and then clicking another control so that the textbox looses its focus.

Comment: Try setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged

Comment: @Matt: I've just checked whether I am setting another binding somewhere in my code - but that's not the case - the above one is the only one (on this textbox). Regarding the XAML: I have ine UserControl which is comprise of several textboxes. At runtime i am instantiating a couple of these UserControls in code and on every instantiation i am creating a Binding for every textbox.

Comment: @BalamBalam: It seems that there is no PropertyChanged - property to choose from _in Silverlight_. I can only assign UpdateSourceTrigger.Default and UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit.

Comment: @Marc Your binding code works fine, so it has to be something to do with the way you're binding your data. Can you create a separate project and re-create a small sample that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Rachel: That#s a good idea but unfortunately I think it's to hard to extract all portions of code that are involved to create an equivalent new project in order to try to reproduce the situation. But I will add the portions of code where I create my XAML objects as well as the DataContext object to my above question :)

Comment: Hi.. tested your code in a brand new project and it worked for me first try.

Comment: @NestorArturo: Thank you :) It really seems that my problem lies somewhere else and not inside here. I've just edited my question above to give more insight in what I am actually doing ...

Comment: But I still can't understand it ! When a textbox is getting updated correctly when data changes, why does the other way don't .. I am really stuck to it ...

Comment: @Marc Can you show the XAML of `LegItem`, particularly `paxTextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

Since you mentioned your binding was actually to a custom `UserControl` and not actually a `TextBox`, I would suggest looking into the XAML of your `UserControl` and making sure it is binding the data correctly

---

**Old Answer**

I did a quick test with a new Silverlight project and noticed that the startup project is `SilverlightApplication1.Web`, not `SilverlightApplication`.

This means that the breakpoint in the setter won't actually get hit when I run the project. You'll notice the breakpoint circle is just the outline, and the color isn't filled in. If you hover over it, it will say

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document

If I start `SilverlightApplication1` instead of the `.Web` version, the breakpoint gets hit.

The property **is** getting changed correctly regardless of which version I startup, however the breakpoint isn't getting hit if I start the project with the `.Web` version. I suspect this is your issue.

Comment: Rachel, thank you very much for spending so much effort in my problem. When I set breakpoints and step into my ViewModel class I can see that my data value really hasn't change. That makes me believe that the binding is really not working downwards. Again, when I am altering some of the data-values in this ViewModel class the correct textbox retrieves the correct change what makes me believe that every textbox is linked to right data attribute via the right binding. Again, Thank you !

Comment: @Marc How are you verifying that the data entered in the TextBox is not getting saved to the data object? I started out using a breakpoint, however noticed it wasn't being hit. I then created a 2nd TextBox bound to the same data item, and noticed both got updated when I updated either one.

Comment: OK I think I get your point. I am doing the following to verify: I simply place a breakpoint at the InsertLeg() method which is located in my ViewModel class.So everytime I am adding a LegItem this method is called in order to generate a new 'ViewModel-Leg' and places it inside a list. So I add some new LegItems, alter the values of some textboxes,click add which leads the execution pause inside my ViewModel where the list is located. Then I look inside the list and notice that all Leg - objects are unmodified although i've just altered some textboxes that are bound to some of their attributes

Comment: @Marc That makes me think the item that is being bound is not the exact same object reference as the one in your list. When you test updating the data value, do you do it the same way? For example, in your `InsertLeg()` method, update one of the items in the collection and see if it updates the TextBlock in the UI.

Comment: Rachel, I really have to apologize because i've just found the error. You were true from the beginning on - the error had nothing to do with the binding or the setup of the View-ViewModel architecture. Btw, regarding your last comment: I did verify it exactly in the way you described :) The error which made both of us have some really headache (hope your's was not as strong as mine _smile_) lied in the TextBox itself: It is not a default clr TextBox but an altered version of mine - userControl that comprise a TextBlock and a TextBox inside its ControlTemplate. [continue ...

Comment: ...] I did this because I had slight different requirements in presenting the text and entering it than a normal textBox would offer to me. But regardless of the visuall appearance of the text the string itself should be the same in both the TextBlock and the TextBOx so I linked them together via ElementPropertyBinding .. And to be able to enter text into my whole modified TextBox I .... guess what ? ... Exactly! ... I linked the TextProperty of the embeeded TextBox to its comprising control via TemplateBinding.

Comment: So the textbox was indeed already be bound and could not be bound again by me again. I have replaced my textbox with a standard clr textbox and of course there it is working as it is supposed to be. IT WAS YOUR LAST COMMENT where you wanted to see some XAML code that made me have look inside the XAML code and there I noticed. So you definitely solved my proplem and I can't say THANK YOU as often as you deserve it ! :)

Comment: when you state your comment on having a look inside the XAML code as an Answer I can mark it accordingly :)

Comment: @Marc lol at least you got it sorted out. And I browse SO for entertainment, so no headache here. :) I enjoy the little puzzles people give me to solve

Comment: @Marc And sure, I've edited my answer to suggest looking at the XAML of the UserControl your data is bound to :)

Comment: hehe, yes that was more a riddle than a puzzle :) And I understand this way of entertainment - Its the same for me :) So let me have sent greetings to NYC from Austria :)